# Can the Minor Illusion spell hide the "visibly magical" nature of an object conjured by the Minor Conjuration feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, vision-and-light, illusion

A Wizard who chooses the [School of Conjuration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#SchoolofConjuration) at level 2 can use Minor Conjuration (PHB, p. 116) to conjure a smallish non-magical item that they have seen before such as a hammer, a gem, gold coin etc. One of the properties of that item is that it emits a visible magical aura.

Can the [*minor illusion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion) spell stop this aura and make the item appear to be non-magical? It can create the illusion of an object; therefore, can that illusion be placed over the conjured item and remove the visible aura?

Comment: I removed the part where you were asking for "any spells or affects" because that would be a broader and different question than specifically asking about minor illusion's interaction with minor conjuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Not if the objects are the same size

It has been [stated elsewhere](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/928360819548553216) by Jeremy Crawford that illusions which hide something do not hide the effects of that thing, specifically the emitting of light.

> The invisibility spell doesn't prevent you or your gear from emitting light, yet that light makes you no less invisible. The light appears to be coming from the air. Spooky!

The aura is around the object in question: by creating an illusion of the same object (but mundane) you create the image of the object but not the air around it: so the aura would remain.

However, you could certainly create an illusion of a larger object, and hide the aura within it (such as creating the illusion of a basket around a conjured knife). The DM would have to decide how large the aura is, but it presumably is not larger than a 5' cube. So as long as you're willing to create a large enough illusion (such as a 5' cube of granite) you can definitely hide your conjured object's aura within it.

Keep in mind though: **the illusion is fixed in space and cannot move** (for that, you'd need *silent image* or some higher level spell). So although you could conceal the object with this illusion, you couldn't actually do anything with the conjured object while making it appear normal. You'd probably be better off just putting the object inside your shirt.